# Edit or Create Graph Style Sheets for WebAdmin

Tags: neo4j, stylesheet, web-admin

I have updated to neo4j 2.0 and I am currently becoming desperate trying to edit the web admin stylesheets for my graph. There was a comfortable styles editor in the old version, I can not find in the new one.

There is a message displayed, which is probably explaining, how to edit the style sheet: "Drop Cypher script file to importDrop a grass-file here to import". However I do not understand the message.

Does anybody know any tutorial for editing graph style sheets for neo4j 2.0?

Thanks in advance,

Iwanai

Answer (score 0):

In Neo4j 2.0.0 you cannot edit the stylesheet inplace. Instead you have to download the stylesheet using the download symbol right to the caption text "Graph Style Sheet". Edit the downloaded file locally using your favourite editor and use drag & drop it to the designated drop area.

Comment: Thanks, where can I find examples with available style options?

Comment: "designated area"? Where is the "designation"?

Answer (score 0):

Once you download the stylesheet it's pretty easy to open the text file in an editor. You just have to look up color codes per your preferences. 
for example:

```
node {
  diameter: 40px; #you can change this value to your size preference for diameter of the node
  color: #DFE1E3; #this is the value that you need to google.
  border-color: #D4D6D7; # same as above
  border-width: 2px; #width of node border
  text-color-internal: #000000; #pretty obvious
  caption: '{Date}'; 
  font-size: 14px; #also obvious
}

relationship {
  color: #D4D6D7;
  shaft-width: 1px;
  font-size: 4px;
  padding: 3px;
  text-color-external: #000000;
  text-color-internal: #FFFFFF;
}
```

[Here is a good reference for HTML color values](http://www.computerhope.com/htmcolor.htm)