# Style sheet (.grass) on the server?

Tags: neo4j

I'm using Neo4j 2.2.0, community edition, installed on a server. I have been able to successfully download the .grass style sheet, modify it, then drag it back to the browser. This works great, however it only changes the style on my local machine. Seemingly the .grass file lives in the local resources of the browser.

I would like to keep my style sheet on the server & apply it to all users of my database. Can anyone guide me through how I can do this please? I couldn't see anywhere obvious in the db files or the help documentation.

The closest related question I could find is this one [Edit or Create Graph Style Sheets for WebAdmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21409282/edit-or-create-graph-style-sheets-for-webadmin), which seems to imply that it's not really possible.

Cheers,
Andy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of version 3.2, now you can set your own `.grass` file as default stylesheet for your Neo4j browser visualization. You can set the configuration in the `neo4j.conf` file as:

```
browser.post_connect_cmd=style <path to your .grass file>
```

More info [here](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-browser/issues/171)

Comment: from some servers this doesn't work (even if they are allowed in conf file) (and for me hosting it in import directory didn't work either), in case it happens to anyone else too, my solution was hosting the grass file on github and using the raw file link from there.

Answer (score 2):

Right now it's not possible automatically (except for copying / reading out the local browser storage and updating it in the other browsers).

The feature is being worked on but not ready for public usage yet.

[image: Neo4j Browser Grass Local Storage]

Comment: Is this available now, a year later?