# Why is only 'id' available for 'caption' when I only create labels?

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-browser

For example, for this statement:

```
create (s:Student), (t:Teacher)
```

In Neo4j Browser, only ID is used as caption. Why doesn't 'Student' and "Teacher" show to be chosen as caption as well? I want to model the domain so I don't want to create instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For doing graphical modeling the domain, try using `apoc.meta.graph()` from [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/). It shows a graphical view of what labels are in your graph, and how nodes with those labels relate to each other via relationships. You just need a couple sample nodes in your graph with the appropriate labels and relationships.

Answer (score 0):

You can change what appears as the caption using  a CSS (‘grass’) styleshert and the caption selector - see [Edit or Create Graph Style Sheets for WebAdmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21409282/edit-or-create-graph-style-sheets-for-webadmin#21416338)